# How can I use the approve function of an NFT contract on the client side?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, nft

I'm working on an application that interacts with an Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) contract. Specifically, I'm looking to utilize the approve function of an NFT contract on the client side. The approve function allows an NFT owner to give permission for a specific address to transfer their NFT token on their behalf.

My use case involves the owner of an NFT token wanting to grant approval for a specific address to transfer their token. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this functionality securely and efficiently.

**Here are the specific details of my use case:**

- I have the deployed address of the NFT contract.
- I have the tokenId of the NFT.
- msg.sender is the owner of the specific NFT tokenId.
- I'm using a library or framework that provides a signer for Ethereum transactions.

**What I would like to know is:**

- Are there any existing APIs or methods that allow me to utilize the approve function of the NFT contract directly from the client side?
- How can I securely initiate the approve transaction with the necessary parameters (contract address and tokenId) using the signer (msg.sender) I have available?
- Are there any specific considerations or best practices I should be aware of when implementing this functionality?

I would appreciate any insights, code examples, or references to relevant documentation that can help me accomplish this task. Thank you in advance!

**Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
const tokenId= tokenId; // tokenId of the NFT

const nftContractAddress = '0x...'; // Address of the NFT contract

// Signer setup code omitted for brevity

// Function to call the `approve` function of the NFT contract
async function approveNFT() {
  // ... Code to set up the signer using the ownerAddress of tokenId(NFT)

  // How can I call the `approve` function of the NFT contract here?
  // Is there an API or method available that allows me to interact with the contract functions on the client side?

  // Example: Approve a specific address to transfer the NFT
  // await nftContract.approve(addressToApprove, tokenId);
}

approveNFT();
```